# Twitterizer get user information

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, twitter

I have a questions on using Twitterizer
I want to get the TwitterUser model for getting the user's information from the response request on Twitter, but i don't know the way.

This is my code:

```
public ActionResult Logon(string oauth_token, string oauth_verifier, string ReturnUrl)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oauth_token) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(oauth_verifier))
        {
            UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(this.Request.Url);
            builder.Query = string.Concat(
                builder.Query,
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(builder.Query) ? string.Empty : "&",
                "ReturnUrl=",
                ReturnUrl);

            string token = OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterConsumerKey"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterConsumerSecret"],
                builder.ToString()).Token;

            //return Redirect(OAuthUtility.BuildAuthorizationUri(token, true).ToString());
            Response.Redirect(string.Format("http://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token={0}&force_login=true", token), true);  
        }

        var tokens = OAuthUtility.GetAccessToken(
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterConsumerKey"],
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterConsumerSecret"],
            oauth_token,
            oauth_verifier);
        OAuthTokens accessToken = new OAuthTokens();
        accessToken.AccessToken = tokens.Token;
        accessToken.AccessTokenSecret = tokens.TokenSecret;
        accessToken.ConsumerKey =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterConsumerKey"];
        accessToken.ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterConsumerSecret"];
        //TwitterUser u = 


        TwitterUser myTwitterUser = .............. 
        ..............


    }
```

I already get the OAuthTokens.After the "........."  i don't know what to do next to get the information for the user.

Anyone can help me.Thansk a lot

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking at the [`documentation`](http://www.twitterizer.net/):

```
TwitterResponse<TwitterUser> myTwitterUser = TwitterUser.Show(accessToken, "twit_er_izer");
```